# What are the energy cells for?

Tags: a-dark-room

Over the course of the game I explored every tile of the map; I ended up with a couple dozen energy cells, but never found a use for them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are used as the bullet equivalent for laser rifles, which can sometimes be found in boreholes.

Comment: Huh, I never found *anything* but alien alloy in the boreholes.

Comment: I found one on a battlefield (or whatever it's called)

Comment: Laser rifles are rare.